# Getting a Seg Fault when reading in Data from a text file in C

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to take information from a text file and read it in, in my main i get the length of the file in bytes, as well as the name of the file to ensure that it exists, and pass it to this method.

I have some test code in there for seeing where the issue is, but I can not seem to see where the seg fault comes from, the fgetc return value matches the value its stored in which is the only thing I can think of.

```c
uint32 getCode(char *fileA, int count){
   //creating variables to store the data we are reading in
   int buffer = 0;
   register uint64 total = 0;

   //opening with rb ensures that all file types will be readable
   FILE *file;
   if(file= fopen(fileA, "rb")){
      printf("\nfilename: %s\ncount: %d\n",fileA,count);
   }
   // while loop reading in 32 bits at a time or 4 bytes
   while(count > 0){
      buffer = fgetc(file);
      count--;
      printf("\n%s", buffer);
   }

   fclose(file);
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: Use `%c` format when you print, now you pass `int` to `%s`. Also, enable compiler warnings.

Comment: You also use `file` even if it fails to open, it could be a null pointer.

Comment: `printf("\n%s", buffer);` ??  Buffer is an int.

Comment: Really tempted to edit the title of the question and change it to: `Getting a Seg Fault when calling printf with invalid format string`.  Reading the data is not relevant to the seg fault.

Comment: Always compile with ***Warnings Enabled***. It is apparent you don't, or are choosing to ignore them. For gcc/clang, minimum use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (suggest `-Wshadow` as well) for VS use `/W3` and do not accept code until it compiles without warning.

Answer (score 0):

The segmentation fault comes from `printf("\n%s", buffer);` -- your `buffer` is not a string, and you may get much better results printing using format `'%c'`

And yeah, the comment `// while loop reading in 32 bits at a time or 4 bytes` is a bit misleading, since you're reading 1 byte at a time.